# Why isn't my new Iolloi wifi thermostat powering on?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, advice

I've tried replacing a Honeywell mechanical T6360 with this Iolloi Wi-Fi (Alexa compatible) cheap thermostat. However, when I wired the mains (UK) N and L to the appropriate terminals nothing happened, so I tried the the wire from pin 3 of the Honeywell in terminals 3,4,5 and 6 yet still get nothing. Can anyone offer any advice or is the unit perhaps faulty?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Attaching wires to various terminals is unlikely to solve your issue or determine if the new thermostat is faulty, it needs to be wired correctly to operate correctly. If your thermostat is using line voltage (230VAC, apparently) it is **dangerous** to do this kind of testing.

Line 3 from your Honeywell looks to be typically a heating or cooling load in most configurations, (Line connects to terminal 1 or 2, is switched by the thermostat, and outputs on terminal 3 to the heater/AC).

The old Honeywell thermostat has several possible configurations though; maybe identifying which of those you had will help you wire up the new one correctly (safely).

[image: Honeywell thermostat wiring configurations from the manual]

Comment: Thanks Fredrick, I was unaware that there were different models of that Thermostat. A good starting point would be to determine the correct model I suppose. Also yes I completely agree, testing of that type is so dangerous, for some reason I came to the conclusion I was dealing with a signal wire rather that a voltage wire and didnt think straight at all. Shoud be able to pin down the correct model with your provided diagram ? I assuming that is all the models (A-C) ?

Comment: It's not clear to me that these are different thermostat models (besides the shared T4360/T6360 text at the top), I interpret this page to be different terminal uses for the various equipment you could have connected. The way I would use this is to determine 1) what equipment you have and 2) how it was connected to the Honeywell before, and use that to figure out which wires should connect to which terminals on the new thermostat.

Comment: Did you figure out the wiring?